# How fo show if $(R,+)$ is cyclic group then is commutative

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that $(R,+)$  is cyclic group,   then $R$ is a commutative ring.

I know if $R$ is cyclic then 
$ R= \left<a\right>= \{a^n , n \in \Bbb Z\}$.

I do not have  any  idea for solving problem.can any one prove this problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know about ring homomorphisms and such?

Comment: Prove that Associative  , identity and inverse and commuter law

Comment: @Bungo Just because there's a natural way to define multiplication doesn't mean that that's how it's defined. You have to show that that's the _only_ way to define multiplication (preferably through distribution).

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*. Show that the additive group underlying $R$ is cyclic if and only if it is generated by $1$ and then consider the unique ring homomorphism $ℤ → R,~1 ↦ 1$.

If $a$ is a generator of $⟨R, +, 0⟩$, then $1 = na = an$ for some $n ∈ ℤ$. What does this tell you about $a$? What does this tell you about the additive group homomorphism $R → R,~x ↦ ax$?